# Unable to access my virtual host from the same network using IP address

Tags: php, apache, configuration, config, vhosts

I'm trying to run two different sources in xampp (one for admin one for users).
I have found one solution by using httpd-vhosts.conf.
In C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf file I have added below config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\user\www"
ServerName 192.169.9.99
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\user\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\www"
ServerName 192.169.9.99.co    
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I can able to see user and admin pages running in 192.169.9.99 and 192.169.9.99.co
But, here my problem is, I tried with another system that present in my same network.
It has given proper result for 192.169.9.99 but not for 192.169.9.99.co

192.169.9.99.co redirecting to 99.co website.

Where I did wrong, Is I missed anything?
There are any other solutions for achieving this requirement?

Is this possible to achieve this?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Start


<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\www"
ServerName 192.169.9.99.co    
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\auction\frontend\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#next

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\user\www"
ServerName 192.169.9.99
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\auction\frontend\www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

192.169.9.99  Will be found earlier because the match.

VirtualHost *:80

**192.169.9.99**

**192.169.9.99**.co

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But now also I'm facing same problem.
It's redirecting to 99.co website.

Answer (score 0):

I have added "Listen 8081" in **httpd.conf**, so that now my xammp will listen 80 and 8081 ports.
  In **httpd-vhosts.conf** I have added

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\www"
</VirtualHost>
```

Document root for port 80 will taken from httpd.conf file.
  Now I tried with another system that in my network, on **192.169.9.99** My **user** site is running.
  In **192.169.9.99:8081** My **admin** site is running.